# Unexpected json string when json_encode array having object's value in php

Tags: php, json

Object having a value `var $error_code="100";`
I can set this value inside a function as

```
$this->error_code=$simpleXml->error_code;  // eg:214
```

I can create its object and print value using json_encode as

```
 echo $obj->error_code; //print value 214
 $code=$obj->error_code;
 $set=array("error_code" => $code,"message" =>"topup failed");
 echo json_encode($set);
```

I got response as

```
214 {"error_code":{"0":"214"},"message":"topup failed"}
```

but I expect output as

```
{"error_code":"214","message":"topup failed"}
```

what is the actual problem for getting

```
{"0":"214"}
```

on output even if $code print value 214 ?

Comment: what is dump of `$obj` ?

Comment: there is no way json_encode() would output invalid json. it either outputs VALID json, or it outputs a boolean false to signify failure...

Comment: Object ( [balance] => 5 [username] => werwerw [password] => ewrewrwer [oprid] => -1 [destination] => [transactionid] => [error_txt] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Fraud suspicion ) [error_code] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 221 ) )

Comment: I think problem with assigning value by simplexml obj.is it ok?

Comment: Get rid of your first `echo` statement, as it is producing output.

Comment: yes.The first statement echo $obj->error_code; print value 214.I checked its page source.Its simply only contain 214.

Comment: I am able to check  its value using if as     if($obj->error_code=="221")
                                            echo "valid";
                                            else
                                            echo "invalid";and get output valid

Answer (score 1):

Change this line,

```
$code=$obj->error_code;
```

to

```
$code=$obj->error_code->0;
```

Also remove

```
echo $obj->error_code;
```

to get

```
{"error_code":"214","message":"topup failed"}
```

Comment: It printed as {"error_code":{},"message":"topup failed"}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
echo $obj->error_code; //print value 214
$code=$obj->error_code;
$set=array("error_code" => $code,"message" =>"topup failed");
echo json_encode($set);
```

Just use:

```
$code = $obj->error_code;
echo json_encode(array("error_code" => $code,"message" =>"topup failed"));
```

Remove the other lines, they are **unnecessary**.

**Edit:**  Add the `[0]` after `$obj->error_code`

Comment: get the same output {"error_code":{"0":"221"},"message":"topup failed"}.

Comment: I set value from a simplexmlobject

Comment: then I got {"error_code":{},"message":"topup failed"}